# Deletion FAQ might need an additional entry

Tags: feature-request, deleted-answers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Why are some posts removed” doesn't address deletion due to migration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106954/why-are-some-posts-removed-doesnt-address-deletion-due-to-migration)

I love the new addition to the deleted indicator on answers:

[image]

However, questions can be deleted because questions are migrated, however this isn't reflected in the FAQ anywhere.

I don't know if this really affects users, as I guess they will be re-directed to the new, migrated question these days, but is there any possibility they could see that note on a migrated question?

Comment: To the mod who handles the dupe flag I submitted for this post: I realized after the fact that the question [“Why are some posts removed” doesn't address deletion due to migration](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/106954/146495) is much newer than this one.  Merge/close in whatever direction you decide is best.

Answer (score 1):

I was about to post this as a feature request, but since you raised this issue already I'll propose it as a modification of yours.

When an answer is deleted due to a migration, the generic deletion message with a link to the FAQ should not be shown. Instead, a different sentence should be shown:

> Your answer was migrated to <other site> along with the question.

There is no need to add yet another case to the deletion FAQ.